# Change if statement from variable

Tags: c#, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

Not sure if the question is correct, but here is what I am trying to accomplish.

I am running a for-loop in which i want to change the if-statement in each loop.

Here is the example:

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){

    int currentField = field;

    var context1=currentField;
    int curprogr=0;

    switch (i){
    case 0:
        context1 = currentField % 10 != 0;
        curprogr = 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        context1 = Mathf.Floor(currentField/10) != 0;
        curprogr = 10;
        break;
    case 2:
        context1 = currentField % 10 != 0 && Mathf.Floor(currentField/10) != 0;
        curprogr = 11;
        break;
    }

    while(context1){ // Here is where I want it to chnage for each time the loop runs through //
        // Some logic here... //
    }
}
```

I get this error: Cannot implicitly convert type `bool' to`int' in every switchcase in regards to the context1.

Hope this makes sense and any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: u r assigning int variable currentfield to context first so it consider the var variable as int..later you  are trying to assing a bool function context1 thats why this error is comign

Comment: What is ur if-else condition ?

Comment: What do you want your `while` condition to be, as a number is not true or false (unless you actually specify your comparison)

Comment: Thats because you are trying to assign `currentField % 10 != 0` (bool) to `context1` which is int. and there is no implicit/explicit casting defined for it.

Comment: You are asking a question about `if1, but you have a `while` loop. Various answers are commenting on `int` vs `bool`, but what are you anticipating happens in the `while` loop? Does context change? Should it be a `while`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`context1` is an `int` since you have assigend an `int` to it here:

```
int currentField = field;
var context1 = currentField;
```

but later you are assigning a `bool`, f.e here:

```
context1 = currentField % 10 != 0;
```

The [`!=`-operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz250sf.aspx) either returns `true` or `false`, so you cannot assign it to that variable.

So just make it a bool variable:

```
bool context1 = false;
```

I also think that you actually want to use an `if` instead of a `while`-loop.

So change it to

```
if(context1)
{ 
    // Here is where I want it to change for each time the loop runs through //
}
```

Why i think that? Because you mentioned `if` in the title and it seems that you dont want to change the condition in the `while`-loop which makes it an  infinite loop.

Comment: Ahhh, didn't see the forest due to the tree's :-) Thanks Tim.

Comment: Meaningful variable names and specifying types instead of using `var` help to avoid these issues ;)

Comment: How will potentially ending up with a `while(true)` help here? You are explaining why the code doesn't compile, but not what is potentially wrong with the code at a more fundamental level.

Comment: @DavidArno: you're right: i have edited my answer accordingly. A loop doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 1):

you can use delegate function like Predicate to achive this functionality. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Here you assign `var context1=currentField;` and in case Statement you are trying to assign boolean value so it wrong.

See case 0:

```
context1 = currentField % 10 != 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int currentField = field;
```

`var context1=currentField;` //var will consider as int because you are assigning int variable to it
so better assingn `true` or `false` to var context1 first

Later in case you are assinging bool function to context1 so the cast conversion error occurs

Answer (score 0):

The expression `currentField % 10 != 0` returns a `bool`.

Your `context1` variable is of type `int`, so you can't assign that expression to that variable.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, but consider using your expression in an ***if*** statement:

```
if(currentField % 10 != 0)
{
     curprogr = 1;
}
break;
```